# How to get a 2D array of windows from a 1D array in Rust using ndarray?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I have a 1-Dimensional [`ndarray::Array`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html), and I'm trying to compute windows on that Array.

At the end of this, I want a 2-dimensional `Array2`, with one dimension being the size of the window, and one being however many windows there are.

So if the 1D array is `n` elements long, and the window size is `k`, I want to be able to do this:

```rust
use ndarray::Array;

let n: usize = 1000;
let k: usize = 10;


let one_d_array = Array::<u32>::ones((n));

let windows = one_d_array.windows(k); // <- somehow I end up with a 2D array (k, n-k) from here
```

and end up with a 2D array. What's the best way to do that?

**Broader context**: I'm using [RustFFT](https://crates.io/crates/rustfft) to generate a spectrogram of a sound file, and my workflow is:

- Load the sound file
- Get samples from that file (comes as a `Vec<i16>`)
- Create windows of that array and select every `n`th window (for a given window and overlap ratio)
- Compute a DFT on each window
- Put that into a graph

Using 2D arrays would be a lot easier in this workflow than `Vec<Vec<T>>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I have misunderstood the question but the following [snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dc076e7645d32e8296a119b484b88149)

```
    let win_size = 2;
    let win_count = 2;
    let a = Array::from_shape_vec((win_size, win_count).f(), vec![1, 2, 3, 4]).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}",a);
```

would give you a 2-D representation of your 1-D input.